# Executing Javascript from another page using AJAX

Tags: jquery, yahoo-api

I am trying to get a specific div with some Javascript inside that div, from another page  using AJAX, but for some reason the Javascript doesn't load... I can only see the HTML.

What am I doing wrong?
This is my code:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'web.php', type: 'GET', datatype: 'html', success: 
    function (html) { 
        var data = $('#content',$(html)).html();
        YAHOO.plugin.Dispatcher.process($('#content').get(0), data);  
    } 
});
```

Comment: change datatype to javascript or application/javascript maybe. just a hunch

Comment: What is returned in your html var? ID a container? Try to address your target element using a unique ID if possible.

Comment: What do you mean you only see the HTML? When you run the page, you're not seeing your javascript in the page? Or after you call your ajax function?

Comment: @Yatrix after I call the ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
 $.ajax({ url: 'web.php', type: 'GET', datatype: 'html', success: 
     function (html) { 
        $("script").append(html);
         var data = $('#content',$(html)).html();
         YAHOO.plugin.Dispatcher.process($('#content').get(0), data);  
     } 
 });
```

Comment: This could result in a bloated DOM. `script` shouldn't have any children.

Comment: If the document contains multiple `<script>` tags, the `script`s from AJAX will execute multiple times.

Comment: For some reason when I tried using this script and it just refreshed my page to a blank page and I get lots of js errors

Answer (score 0):

If your .js isn't loading, there's probably a syntactical error somewhere and your browser will use the previously cached version. I'd go back over my last few changes to see what I messed up - a missing bracket, paren, semicolon, etc.

Comment: The ajax function is being called. and even the #content div loads all the html. but theres also javascript on that page. the javascript aint loading..

Comment: I tried to use this function and I get this javascript error: ReferenceError: reference to undefined XML name *::*
[Break On This Error]  

<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />

Comment: If the ajax function is working, that's not the problem. If the javascript within the page you're injecting the html into is not showing, then there's a syntax error you'll have to weed out.